# Realize parallel sessions with PHP

Tags: php

How can I realize a parallel session with PHP? I intend to login in as admin and now I can see a list of normal users. The admin user should be able to log in as a normal user in a new browser tab by clicking a user.

I tried to give sessions a unique name and id but this still haven't work.

Comment: use two dimensional array for session like $_SESSION['user_type']['sess_name'].

Comment: This is the basics of user roles and rights. Just makes access roles, whereas the Admin can also be a normal User, Customer etc. No need to split it up.

Comment: Open an incognito window. Session per tab will confuse the hell out of your users.

Comment: You should explain the goal for what you try this. Perhaps there is another solution to solve the problem.

Comment: Give the admin user a drop down so they can change a session variable like 'activeUser'.   Then read from this var for page display.

Comment: This has nothing to do with sessions but more with user managament (as mentioned by @Allendar).

Comment: @nietonfir I totally disagree. A user having multiple roles is way more logical than linking different users to each other, or however you want to do it. The only other thing that would work is *Impersonation*, which I mostly use when building a B2B system, where a Sales Agent can bulk-buy for a customer under his supervision.

Comment: @Allendar I was a bit vague, imo Roles, Access Control Lists, Authentication, Authorization, etc. all belong to user management in a broader sense. However, I don't know of any implementation (especially in PHP) where a parallel session is instantiated, in the end it all happens either in the session of the "admin", especially impersonation (where you want to keep the possibilty to e.g. switch back to the admin user) or by generating a new one.

Comment: My goal is to build an application where normal users can do their work. When a normal user can not perform his duties, the admin should be able to log in as a user to perform the users tasks. The admin is able to choose the user from a user list.

Answer (score 0):

Session cookies are stored in the browser for the whole browser session, so you can't separate them between windows.

Either you write your own session handler code, that does not use cookies, but appends something like '&sessionid=BLARGROB' to every link, or just install two browsers on you machine. Use Internet explorer for your user session and Firefox for your admin session, and Chrome for whatever else you'd like to do on your site without invalidating the other sessions. Using several browsers is a good idea to test your layout anyway.